# How can I enable graphics on local macOS from remote Linux using SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, x11, osx

`host`: `Ubuntu 64-bit`

`local`: `macOS 10.13 64-bit`

I'm attempting to run a program on a remote Linux machine through `ssh`, and I want the GUI to appear on my local macOS laptop.

When I execute `ssh -v -X user@host` or `ssh -v -Y user@host`, I receive two messages that may be worth noting:

With -X flag:

```
debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: Untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
```

With -Y flag:

```
debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding
```

When I log onto the `host`, and execute `which xauth` I get the output: `/usr/bin/xauth`, which is confusing me because `ssh` is stating that there is no `xauth` program.

Additionally, when I do end up running the program thru `ssh` on my mac (just the command line version, no graphics), I get these errors:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  23
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

How can I fix this so that I can enable graphics to run on my local mac from the host Linux computer?

Edit: When I type `which xquartz` on my local mac: `/opt/X11/bin/xquartz`

Comment: Do you have an X server running on the macOS machine, for example XQuartz?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes I have XQuartz on my mac, it's in `/opt/X11/bin/xquartz`.

Comment: Is out of question including that in the question?

Comment: Maybe `ssh` tries to use a local `xauth` to get the authorization information.

Answer (score 2):

1. The problem is that ssh looks for `xauth` in wrong path - on Ubuntu it is `/usr/bin/xauth` but on macOS it is `/opt/X11/bin`. This can be solved by edit your local ssh config file. (`~/.ssh/config`, add `XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth`)
2. It seems a problem with XQuartz. I know one "solution" is to downgrade XQuartz to version 2.7.8.